# Fix CAps LOck delay in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: keyboard, 21.04, capslock

I am one of those people who uses <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> to capitalize text, so the issue is quite annoying on Linux distros where there is a delay. I had found a fix for this, which included changing the `key<CAPS>` data in a keyboard map and reloading the keyboard map to my keyboard. This fix no longer works in Ubuntu 21.04. Here's what I was doing before:

```
// Create keyboard map
xkbcomp -xkb $DISPLAY myxkbmap
nano myxkbmap

// Replace the part that says key<CAPS> with this:

key <CAPS> {     repeat=no,     type[group1]="ALPHABETIC",     symbols[group1]=[ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock ],     actions[group1]=[ LockMods(modifiers=Lock), Private(type=3,data[0]=1,data[1]=3,data[2]=3) ]   };

// Reload the file
xkbcomp myxkbmap $DISPLAY
```

***It should be noted that this is not a perfect fix. When typing quickly you'll notice that the word `I'm` will result in `I"m`. This is a major improvement over `I'M` nonetheless.***

This works in *almost* every distro and has historically worked for me in every Ubuntu version to date. When I attempt this in 21.04, it doesn't work and I'm greeted with this warning after creating the keyboard file:

> Warning:          Could not load keyboard geometry for :0
> BadName (named color or font does not exist)
> Resulting keymap file will not describe geometry

This is the only difference that I noticed between creating the fix on 20.10 and 21.04, yet when I make the changes and reload the file it doesn't fix the issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm not going to start using <kbd>shift</kbd> haha I would rather use Windows. Clearly, they changed something between 20.10 and 21.04 that's affecting this.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**
Solution is here: [Fix CAps LOck delay in Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338237/fix-caps-lock-delay-in-ubuntu-21-04#1396550)

Ubuntu 21.04 uses Wayland as its default display server, not Xorg. Xorg-specific configuration and tweak tools (which `xkbcomp` is) will not work on Wayland.

As a temporary measure, I would recommend to **just not use Wayland** until it's ready and has a considerable user base. Without an active user base, there is always way too many bugs and no one to fix them.

To switch to Xorg:

1. Log out.
2. Click on your profile.
3. On the bottom right corner a display server selection button will appear. Click on it and select *Ubuntu on Xorg*.

   [image: Display server choice]
4. Now log back in and everything should work.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone still is waiting for answer, there is a solution for both Wayland and Xorg.

Solution: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/caps-lock-behaviour-wayland/79868/8

You will have to edit root file. Would recommend **nautilus-admin** if using nautilus file manager (nautilus-admin does not work properly on Ubuntu 21.10, other versions are fine), but regular chmod will do the trick.

**Instructions**

Open your file/folder manager. Navigate yourself to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` (Ctrl + L). The file you are looking for is called `capslock`, but before you can edit it, rights for that file need to be changed. Right click in that folder and choose **Open in Temrinal**.

Enter command: `sudo chmod 777 capslock`

Now open file `capslock` with your preferred text editor (You might want to make backup of that file just in case).

Replace

```
// This changes the <CAPS> key to become a Control modifier,
// but it will still produce the Caps_Lock keysym.
hidden partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ctrl_modifier" {
    replace key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1] = "ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Caps_Lock ],
        actions[Group1] = [ SetMods(modifiers=Control) ]
    };
    modifier_map Control { <CAPS> };
};
```

with

```
// This changes the <CAPS> key to become a Control modifier,
// but it will still produce the Caps_Lock keysym.
hidden partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ctrl_modifier" {
          key <CAPS> {
              type="ALPHABETIC",
              repeat=No,
              symbols[Group1]= [ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock ],
              actions[Group1]= [ LockMods(modifiers=Lock),
                                 LockMods(modifiers=Shift+Lock,affect=unlock) ]
          };
};
```

Save your changes. Restore file original rights by entering `sudo chmod 644 capslock` into terminal.

Now install **GNOME Tweaks** from your software store if you dont have it installed already or `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.

Open GNOME Tweaks. Navigate to **Keyboard & Mouse** tab. Click **Additional Layout Options** and open **Caps Lock behavior** dropdown. Choose **Caps Lock is also a Ctrl**.

[image]

Reboot your Ubuntu and it should work now. You dont need to keep GNOME Tweaks installed, if you wish you could delete it.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon based on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks for your answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/1396550/1673413, but I tried gnome-tweaks and it didn't work here, so on Mint 21.1 Cinnamon, after replacing some code on capslock file (`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`), we need to activate "Caps lock is also a Ctrl" from "layout keyboard options". placed in: System settings -> *Keyboard* -> *Layouts* -> *Options*... -> check *Make Caps Lock an additional Ctrl* item in the list.

[image: image additional keyboard setting on Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon]

**edited:
note:**
someone might think LM is not Ubuntu, yeah, LM is not Ubuntu.
but, LM is based from Ubuntu.

I put this answer here because there is a similarity of the linux base (ubuntu).
whereas the CApslock DElay keyboard fix for LM itself I've never found that really helps other than the 2 answers before me on this question.

but in these 2 answers, there is something that doesn't work for LM.

that's why I'm trying to add an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is unrelated to Ubuntu. As you may or may not know, LM is not Ubuntu.

Comment: @mikewhatever : yup, LM is not Ubuntu. but, LM is based from Ubuntu.

I put this answer here because there is a similarity of the linux base (ubuntu).
whereas the CApslock DElay keyboard fix for LM itself I've never found that really helps other than the 2 answers before me on this question.

but in these 2 answers there is something that doesn't work for LM, that's why I'm trying to add an answer.

Comment: Well, many distros are based on Ubuntu. If it makes you happier, all of them are off topic here.

Comment: After i used code from this comment https://askubuntu.com/a/1396550/1711808 and used the screenshot steps from this comment https://askubuntu.com/a/1455166/1711808 it worked perfectly for me in LM <3 thanks a lot